# How to literally print superscripts in R not used in labels or legends?

Tags: r, format, rtf, superscript

I know that in a graph one can use expression() to include superscripts, e.g.

```
plot(rnorm(20), xlab = expression(paste("n"^"th")))
```

However, I literally want to print out superscripts, so I can store them in rtf files later. In fact, I want to use them to indicate the degree of statistical significance associated with my regression coefficients (you know, like "0.24^*").

With "`expression(paste("n"^"th"))`", I tried `print()`, `cat()`, `eval()`, and `get()` but none of them worked.

I am currently using the "rtf" package to output ".doc" files. If someone suggests using other ways/packages, it is OK if R itself cannot display rich formats in the console, but the results can be stored in some files anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've seen, the `?plotmath` expressions only work within plots. Nothing in R is optimized for rtf output.

But reading the RTF vignette, it's clear you can write [rtf commands](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm) in your output and there is a command for superscripting. Try

```
library(rtf)

rtf<-RTF("text.doc")
addText(rtf,"Hello\n")
addText(rtf,"0.05{\\super*}\n")
addText(rtf,"0.15*\n")
addText(rtf,"End")
done(rtf)
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you so much! Did you just read it and figure it out, or did you know it all alone?

Comment: I did some research and tested some ideas. It's pretty much how I answer all questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(rnorm(20), xlab = as.character("n^*"))
```

or even

```
plot(rnorm(20), xlab = paste0("n","^","th"))
```

Not sure why you want to use `expression()`

Comment: No, this is not what I want. First, "n^th" does not give me n_superscript_th. Second, it must not be displayed via a graph. It must be either directly displayed in the console or stored in some rtf files.

Comment: `myExpression <- as.name(paste0("n","^","0"))` ??